# Evitar que se limpien datos al dar click en un button con javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

estoy haciendo un proyecto en el que añado elementos al DOM con una función de javascript que es ejecutada por un botón, hasta ahí todo muy bien, efectivamente añade los elementos, pero cuando doy click en el botón nuevamente, este reemplaza lo que ya he añadido (como si refrescara la página), me dí cuenta que el "href" que tiene el botón es el que me borra los elementos, si quito el href (el cual no dirige a nada, solo tiene las variables), logro lo que quiero hacer pero lo necesito por que estoy enviando variables por GET con PHP, alguna idea?, en que estoy fallando?, qué me falta?

Código del botón (HTML):

```
<a class="btn btn-info text-white phone-add" href="?Imagen=<?php print $imagen; ?>&Extension=<?php print $formato?>&Referencia=<?php print ($Referencia?>&Nombre=<?php print $Nombre?>" onclick="validaNombre();">Agregar</a>
```

Código de la Función (JavaScript):

```
function validaNombre() {
    var val = document.getElementsByClassName("PanelNombre")[0].innerHTML;
      if(val != 0) {
      var nuevaFila = document.createElement("TR");
      nuevaFila.innerHTML = "<td>Persiste</td>";
      document.getElementById("tabla_productos").appendChild(nuevaFila);
    }
}
```

Comment: NO necesitas el href para enviar variables por get por medio de PHP en su lugar deberias usar ajax y no ponerte a mezclar el html con PHP, los usuarios tienen la mania de hacerlo, si bien laravel hace algo parecido lo ideal seria que no hicieras una peticion de esa manera, porque segun entiendo estas redirigiendote a la misma pagina pero pasandole parametros `GET` en ese caso para que hacer la peticion `GET` a la misma pagina?, si al enviar los datos tecnicamente ya deberias tenerlos.

Comment: si tu respuesta es que esos datos quieres que luego los procese `PHP` en el mismo archivo entonces hay algo que estas haciendo mal, puesto que no deberias tener en la misma pagina tanto el codigo `PHP` encargado de tratar y hacer cosas con la base de datos o el servidor (backend), como el frontend (`HTML`, `CSS` y `Javascript`) en la misma parte, no solo se considera una mala practica, si no que ademas vulnera la seguridad y hace menos manejable y legible el codigo, en resumen deberias tener `HTML`, `CSS` y `javascript` de un lado y `PHP` del otro, mas no juntos.

Comment: Ahora bien, si se te esta borrando el contenido entonces si te esta redirigiendo, pero te esta redirigiendo a la misma pagina y añadiendole ciertos parametros, en caso de que veas que enrealidad no se esta recargando la pagina entonces debe haber algo que no estas mostrando en tu codigo que borra estos elementos, por ejemplo un `innerHTML` mal asignado.

Comment: gracias por sus aportes, hice los ajustes y pude corregir algunas cosas, pero me di cuenta que lo que realmente me está limpiando los datos es un "form" que tengo en la página (un buscador) y que arroja resultados en la misma, entonces todo lo que pinte, posteriormente va a ser limpiado por el botón de este form, algún truco, sugerencia para esto?, Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Podrias intentar llamando al bootn por un id, y agregandole un preventDefault().

```
<a class="btn btn-info text-white phone-add" id="btn1" href="?Imagen=<?php print $imagen; ?>&Extension=<?php print $formato?>&Referencia=<?php print ($Referencia?>&Nombre=<?php print $Nombre?>" onclick="validaNombre();">Agregar</a>

var btn = document.getElementById('btn1');
btn.preventDefault();
```

Espero te sirva....

Comment: Amigo,  tu respuesta no esta tan mal,  pero tengo 2 observaciones,  la primera es que considero que deberias mejorarla,  ten en cuenta que el OP quiza no tenga los mismos conocimientos que tu,  es decir,  explica por ejemplo: que se hace en el codigo?, para que sirve preventDefault?, por que lo usas? etc,  tu pregunta puede ser util pero le falta mucha explicacion para que el OP entienda lo que haces,  la segunda sugerencia es que eso si lo ejecutas asi probablemente no te de error pero el link te seguira redirigiendo, no te voy a decir el porque de ello.

Comment: Si encuentras el porque de eso que dije arriba,  editas la respuesta,  la cuadras para que no tenga ese problema y das una mejor explicacion al OP te dare mi voto arriba, estas cerca, muy cerca,  pero aun te falta.

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar que un href te redirija, inclusive a la misma pagina, debes poner como objetivo del link un '#'.
te quedaría algo así:

```
<a class="btn btn-info text-white phone-add" href="# ?Imagen=<?php print $imagen; ?>&Extension=<?php print $formato?>&Referencia=<?php print ($Referencia?>&Nombre=<?php print $Nombre?>" onclick="validaNombre();">
```

Comment: Eso no evita que se redirija, de hecho si te redirige, solo que le pone a la pagina al final un # y los parametroz GET.